# error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" on static function call

Tags: c++, static, syntax-error, llvm, global

I have a static memory pool for my allocator:

```
template<typename Tag>
struct AllocatorPool {
  static void initialize(size_t bytes)
  {
    gPool.allocatePool(bytes);
  }
    typedef AllocatorImpl::Pool tPool;
    static tPool gPool;
};
```

Definition of the memory pool:

```
template<typename T> typename AllocatorPool<T>::tPool AllocatorPool<T>gPool;
```

If I want to initialize the pool like this:

```
AllocatorPool<MyClass>::initialize(1024);
```

the compiler outputs the following error for this line:

```
"C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations"
```

I use Xcode 4.6.3 and the Apple LLVM compiler 4.2

Comment: do you have a minimal self-contained compilable example? I'd say the information is not enough to answer the question, i.e. a more localized error message with some context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
template<typename T> typename AllocatorPool<T>::tPool AllocatorPool<T>gPool;
```

to

```
template<typename T> typename AllocatorPool<T>::tPool AllocatorPool<T>::gPool;
// note the scope resolution operator --------------------------------^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten a `::`

```
template<typename T> typename AllocatorPool<T>::tPool AllocatorPool<T>::gPool;
                                                                      ^^
```